# node.js: reconstruct JSON at Promise.all

Tags: json, node.js

I am outputting some JSON in a file (`queries` is an array of calls getting some JSON, all exactly the same format):

```
Promise.all(queries)
.then((data) => writeFile(PATHTOFILE, 'stories', data))
.catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

It works fine but `data` is not valid JSON, since I have

```
],[
```

inbetween all my objects. How do I reconstruct one valid JSON?

Comment: How does your data look?

Comment: [{1,2}] for an individual query, so in the end I get [{1,2}],[{11,22}] when I want   [{1,2},{11,22}]

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Objects (curly braces: `{ }`) must have keys and values. Arrays (square brackets: `[ ]`) can have comma separated values. So... what does `data` actually look like?

Comment: data currently looks like [{1,2}],[{11,22}] (some JSON retrieved in via a REST API where [{1,2}]  is the result of one https request).